# How to remove CSS Class in aspx pages source codes using Regex?

Tags: c#, css, regex, visual-studio-2010

i try to rearrange my sorce files eg: remove all css styles from aspx Pages. 
i have  a file (C:/file:mypage.aspx and 30-40 aspx pages) how can i remove Css style link etc. with using Regex in C#? Please i need your best helps it is important:) I try to write a winforms(.EXE) to rome css property

i want to remove belows everything!

```
   <link href="../Styles/Interm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">

// ERASE EVERYTHING
  </style>
  class="PageHeader"
CssClass="style1"

 CssClass="MyCss",CssFilePath="/test/style.css",CssPostFix="Aqua"
```

MY CODES:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RemoverTags
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           richTextBox1.Text = RemoveWhiteSpaceFromStylesheets(richTextBox1.Text);
        }

        public  string RemoveWhiteSpaceFromStylesheets(string body)
        {
            body = Regex.Replace(body, "type="+"\"text/css\"", "");

            body = Regex.Replace(body, @"[a-zA-Z]+#", "#");

            body = Regex.Replace(body, @"[\n\r]+\s*", string.Empty);

            body = Regex.Replace(body, @"\s+", " ");

            body = Regex.Replace(body, @"\s?([:,;{}])\s?", "$1");

            body = body.Replace(";}", "}");

            body = Regex.Replace(body, @"([\s:]0)(px|pt|%|em)", "$1");



            // Remove comments from CSS

            body = Regex.Replace(body, @"/\*[\d\D]*?\*/", string.Empty);


            Regex r1 = new Regex(@"<style >([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)</style>");
            Match match = r1.Match(body);
            string v = "";
              if (match.Success)
              {
                   v = match.Groups[1].Value;

              }
              body = Regex.Replace(body, v, string.Empty);
              body = Regex.Replace(body, @"<(style|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
              body = Regex.Replace(body, @"<(/style|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
            return body;

        }

    }
}

but not working...
```

Comment: Am I correct in thinking you're wanting to **automatic** removal of the CSS from the page?

Comment: I try to write a winforms(.EXE) to rome css property

Comment: It would be a lot easier to do with an existing tool, rather than writing your own program. [Gawk for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm) could do it. You'd basically be telling it "When you see `<style type="text/css">` start removing lines until you see `</style>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Visual Studio find tool (ctrl+shift+f), go to "find options" and choose regular expression to replace all style elements.